# spring data mongodb custom interface ConflictingBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Following [Spring Data MongoDB](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-mongodb/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-implementations) manual, I have created repository and implementation classes. However when I start my application spring bootstrap fails with

```
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:
Annotation-specified bean name 'mockTestRepositoryImpl' for bean class [com.foo.testapp.mongo.repository.impl.MockTestRepositoryImpl] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.foo.testapp.mongo.repository.impl.MockTestRepositoryImpl]
```

My config and code: (groovy)

```java
package com.foo.testapp.mongo.repository.impl

@Component
class MockTestRepositoryImpl implements MockTestRepositoryCustom {
    MongoOperations mongoOperations   
    @Autowired
    MockTestRepositoryImpl(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations
    }   
    @Override
    MockTest findAndModify(Query query, Update update, FindAndModifyOptions options) {
        return mongoOperations.findAndModify(query, update, options, MockTest)
    }   
    @Override
    boolean exists(Query query) {
        return mongoOperations.exists(query, MockTest)
    }
}
```

Custom interface:

```java
package com.foo.testapp.mongo.repository
public interface MockTestRepositoryCustom {
    MockTest findAndModify(Query query, Update update, FindAndModifyOptions options)
    boolean exists(Query query);
}
```

Spring Data repository:

```java
package com.foo.testapp.mongo.repository
public interface MockTestRepository extends MongoRepository<MockTest, String>, MockTestRepositoryCustom {
List<MockTest> findByDeleted(boolean deleted);
    MockTest findByIdAndDeleted(String id, boolean deleted);
    @Query(value = "{ 'deleted' : ?0 }", fields = "{ 'name' : 1 }")
    List<MockTest> findAllBasicInfo(boolean deleted);
}
```

Comment: Try removing `@Component` from `MockTestRepositoryImpl` and let me know what happens

Comment: It worked without @Component. Thx. Post this as answer. I will accept. But was wondering why spring data and spring context scan are not working in sync and creating duplicates.

Comment: I added it as an answer. That is a good question that you pose! At first thought Spring should be able to ignore the annotation, but I am betting there is some deep Spring internals stuff preventing that from being easy to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have annotated `MockTestRepositoryImpl` with `@Component`.

You need to remove `@Component` altogether (as you can see in the manual there is no such annotation - but all Spring features work correctly).